# (Could not connect to SMTP host) using PHPMailer in my website on my VPS

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, vps

I have a VPS server.

I have a website hosted on that VPS server.

I have created an email in my VPS which is msacademy@managementskillsacademy.com

I want to use this email to send mails to my users.

I want to send a mail using PHPMailer

Here's my Code :

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Eception;

require "mail/src/PHPMailer.php";
require "mail/src/SMTP.php";
require "mail/src/Exception.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "mainserver.local";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "msacademy@managementskillsacademy.com";
    $mail->Password = "my password";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    

    $mail->setFrom("msacademy@managementskillsacademy.com", "Fahd Abrah");
    $mail->addAddress("msacademy@managementskillsacademy.com");

    
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->Subject = "Thanks for registering";
    $mail->Body = "Thank you so <b>much</b>";
    $mail->AltBody = "Thank you so much";

    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

but i got an error:

```
2022-06-15 14:15:16 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent. Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

How to solve this error?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

A hostname like `mainserver.local` is very unlikely to have a valid certificate, so the connection is likely to fail in the TLS layer due to a missing or unverifiable certificate. Since your failure is at the connection level, set `SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION` to get more info about the early stage of the connection. This might not show much as when you use SMTPS on port 465, there is little feedback if it's breaking.

Since this looks like a local mail server, you probably don't need encryption anyway.

Comment: Ok, What should i do to make my hostname (mainserver.local) have a valid certificate?

Comment: I've set it up to SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION and i got :

Comment: Connection: opening to ssl://mainserver.local:465, timeout=300, options=array()

Comment: Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`localhost.localdomain' did not match expected CN=`mainserver.local'

Comment: Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://mainserver.local:465 (Unknown error)

Comment: I got these errors

Comment: I noticed that when i send a mail to my self i get it correctly. but when i send a mail to a gmail users accounts or outlook users accounts they do not receive it

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: I want to use this email to send mails to my websites's users

Comment: or what can i replace it with to have a valid certificate?

Comment: So you getting exactly the errors I described. Turn off encryption by just not setting `SMTPSecure`.